# PostgreSQL, regex to match text fields with numeric values

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have a column of type text, that contains random values. Some of them are numbers, some other texts, and some other mixed text and numbers. I'm trying to discriminate them as:

```
myfield   is_numeric
____________________
-4        true
0004      true
4.00      true
dog       false
D04       false
04f       false
```

Whereas others are names and other strings. I was using the regular expression

```
SELECT id,
       myfield 
       (myfield::varchar~ '^-?[0-9]*.?[0-9]*$') is_numeric 
FROM mytable
```

To tell wether the row contains a valid number or not. However, I noticed that values like `D04` and `04c` return `true` for that regex, which, for my use case, is a false positive.

Why is this happening? It seems that `^` is matching not necessarily the whole value, but any valid substring of the value. However, values like `D04f` do return `false`, so even if there's a numeric substring in the field, the combination of `^` and `$` operators is doing its job.

I have temporarily resorted to using:

```
SELECT id, 
       myfield
       (myfield::varchar ~ '^-?[0-9]*.?[0-9]*$' 
       AND myfield::varchar !~ '[^0-9\-\.]') is_numeric 
FROM mytable
```

But this seem inneficient (and does not rule out double dots), and I'm still wondering why the regex is correctly ruling out strings that start and end with a non-numeric character, while incorrecly returning true for string that contain only a trailing or leading non numeric character.

Comment: here: `'^-?[0-9]*.?[0-9]*$'` this part `.?` you want to be any character or character `.` ? If it is the second it should be scaped

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
^-?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$
```

I'm asuming `-0.07.5` is invalid (double dot present).

`D04` will return false as well.

The problem in your original regex is that you're not escaping the dot, so it will match any characher, including `D` in your `D04`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: OMG, I went over and over that regex and I didn't see the flaw. Thank you very much.

Comment: Actually this is not good enough `select '.5' ~ '^-?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$'` is false

Comment: It accepts `5.` but not `.5`, doesn't accept [`NaN` or `inifinity`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#:~:text=has%20several%20special%20values%3A-,Infinity,-%2DInfinity%0ANaN), doesn't support [digit grouping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Digit_grouping) or formats that use `,` (or `·` or `'` as alternative decimal points), non-decimal systems.

Answer (score 0):

Any solution based on regular expressions will at best reinvent PostgreSQL's own logic used for casting `text` to `numeric` (or any other type).

In order to stay consistent with PostgreSQL's own definition of the type, it's easiest to just use it:

```sql
create or replace function is_numeric(arg text) 
returns boolean language plpgsql as $$
begin
    perform cast(arg as numeric); --if `arg` is not a valid `numeric`, throws exception here 
    return true;
exception when others then 
    return false;
end $$;
```

More generic form:

```sql
create or replace function is_interpretable_as(arg text, arg_type text) 
returns boolean language plpgsql as $$
begin
    execute format('select cast(%L as %s)', arg, arg_type);
    return true;
exception when others then
    return false;
end $$;
```

Note that this will return `false` regardless of whether the argument or the type is invalid, or both.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/rQzzbOyP)